# Updating salesforce wsdl dynamically using c# code

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce

I have .net application which creating salesforce custom object dynamically but when i am using  that object in my application it does not access it.
what i want to do is, i want to update the wsdl as soon as custom object created.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the Enterprise WSDL, which contains stubs for all objects.  If you expect objects to change (as you do here), then you should instead use the Partner WSDL.  The Partner WSDL does not contain stubs for objects; instead, the partner WSDL file defines a single, generic object (sObject) that represents all of the objects.

For more information, check out the section called "[Using the Partner WSDL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_partner.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_partner.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)" in the Salesforce.com API docs.

Comment: hi amrcn thanks for your reply, can you please give some code or any reference that how to retrieve the sObject definition, means something like getSObject(objName) like describeObject(objName);

Comment: Prashant, see the link I gave in my above answer.  If you click on the "Using the Partner WSDL" book icon on the left hand side navigator frame, you'll find that there are subarticles there, many of which have sample code in them.

Comment: thanks amrcn i have found the solution but i am getting exception when assigning value to datetime field, exception is "'22/2/2013 7:00 PM' is not a valid value for the type xsd:dateTime". I am using .net 4.0 with c# at code behind.

Comment: The datetime format is well documented in Salesforce.com -- it must be specified as given here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm